# How to get words from an input phrase and then get the first and last word alphabetically using C?

Tags: c, string

I am new with C programming and require help with an assignment in C.

I have an input in string using fgets, "apple banana orange pear" and my expected
output is "First word:apple, Last word:pear" which is in alphabetical order. Please help. Thanks.

Here is my script, apologies, new with C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char string[256];
    char word0[20];
    char word1[20];
    char word2[20];
    char word3[20];

    printf( "Enter 5 words seperated by space: " );

    fgets ( string, 256, stdin );

//Trying figure out the scanf part.

//Dignosis inputs.
    printf( "You entered:%s", string );
    printf( "1st word:%s", word0 );
    printf( "2nd word:%s", word1 );
    printf( "3rd word:%s", word2 );
    printf( "4th word:%s", word3 );


//To be doing the comparison here.
//Compare only the first alphabet of the word.
char firstWord[20];
char secondWord[20];

printf(" First word:%s, :ast word:%s",firstWord,secondWord);


getchar();//To pause the script.
}
```

Comment: Post your attempt and specific questions.

Comment: What have you attempted so far? We can help you out and you can learn more if you put effort towards solving the assignment.

Comment: Script posted. Apologies.How to get scanf to read words from a string, using space as a delimiter?

Comment: `Enter 5 words` --> `Enter 4 words`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char string[256];
    char word[4][20];

    printf( "Enter 4 words seperated by space: " );

    fgets ( string, 256, stdin );

    sscanf(string, "%s %s %s %s",
        word[0], word[1], word[2], word[3]);

//Dignosis inputs.
    printf( "You entered:%s", string );
    printf( "1st word:%s\n", word[0] );
    printf( "2nd word:%s\n", word[1] );
    printf( "3rd word:%s\n", word[2] );
    printf( "4th word:%s\n", word[3] );

    qsort(word, sizeof(word)/sizeof(*word), sizeof(*word), (int (*)(const void*, const void*))strcmp);

    printf("First word:%s, :last word:%s\n", word[0], word[3]);

    getchar();//To pause the script.
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1) scan the input string and isolate the words as you find separators

Like "apple" is the next word.

2) find out how to compare two words alphabetically

Like "apple" < "banana".

3) while scanning, keep a trace of the alphabetically first and last words seen so far

Like "apple" is the alphabetically first and also last word seen so far, and later "apple" is the alphabetically first, "banana" is the alphabetically last word seen so far.

Comment: I got the logic but I do not know how to code it in C.

Comment: How can you find a space in a string ?